# How do we include a header which is a angular js component into our index.html

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a **header component** ,which has its **own html** and **js file**
,How do i include this component in my main **index.html**

Comment: Please first read how to write a [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng-include` directive to include an external HTML fragment.

```
<div ng-include="header.html"></div>
```

The above code will include whatever present inside the `header.html` file to be present inside the div element.
You can read more from [ngInclude documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) and [W3 school ngInclude](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-include.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-include directive to include an external HTML, and putting the  css and js file in the index.html

e.g  index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<div ng-include="'includes/header.html'">
<div ui-view=""></div>    
<script src=""></script
```